# Чем отличается QMainWindow и QWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qwidget, qmainwindow

Начал знакомство с *PyQt5* и столкнулся c непониманием в чем отличия между виджетами `QMainWindow` и `QWidget`? 
И такой вопрос, у меня есть класс, который отображает `QWidget`, а можно ли создать класс с `QMainWindow` и туда поместить разные созданные виджеты?

Comment: Можно, Qt Main Window Framework https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#qt-main-window-framework

Comment: а собственно чем отличаются эти классы?

Comment: QMainWindow наследует QWidget и добавляет необходимый минимум элементов, свойственных главному окну: статусбар, главное меню, центральный виджет и что-то там еще

Comment: спасибо, помогли.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Главное окно `QMainWindow`
В более крупных, более сложных и более функциональных приложениях мы обычно наследуем 
класс `QMainWindow` для разработки. Это главное окно предоставляет очень хорошую основу
 для построения пользовательского интерфейса приложения.

Класс главного окна `QMainWindow` предоставляет нам

- строку меню,         `Menu Bar`
- панель инструментов, `Toolbars`
- виджеты `Dock` и
- строку состояния,    `Status Bar`

  и мы можем добавить их столько, сколько захотим.
  Кроме того, это позволяет нам быстро разработать функционально сложное и удобное приложение.

`Блокнот` / **Notepad**
Простое приложение блокнота, чтобы понять, как использовать `QMainWindow`

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import QMimeData
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTextEdit, QAction, QFileDialog, QMessageBox,\
                            QFontDialog, QColorDialog


class Demo(QMainWindow):
    # В начале класса мы устанавливаем несколько переменных класса, которые используются
    # для определения того, был ли сохранен текст, сохраняется ли это в первый раз,
    # и для сохранения пути к файлу:
    is_saved = True
    is_saved_first = True
    path = ''

    def __init__(self):
        super(Demo, self).__init__()

        # Затем мы начинаем добавлять строку меню, панель инструментов и строку состояния:
        self.file_menu = self.menuBar().addMenu('File')
        self.edit_menu = self.menuBar().addMenu('Edit')
        self.help_menu = self.menuBar().addMenu('Help')

        self.file_toolbar = self.addToolBar('File')
        self.edit_toolbar = self.addToolBar('Edit')

        self.status_bar = self.statusBar()

        # Далее нам нужно только добавить различные действия к строке меню и панели инструментов, 
        # то есть QAction. Этот класс обычно используется с панелью меню и панелью инструментов. 
        # Вы можете думать о действии как о команде. Всякий раз, когда пользователь нажимает 
        # на действие, запускается определенная команда, и программа выполняет соответствующую команду. 
        # Теперь нам нужно создать несколько действий:

        self.new_action     = QAction('New', self)
        self.open_action    = QAction('Open', self)
        self.save_action    = QAction('Save', self)
        self.save_as_action = QAction('Save As', self)
        self.close_action   = QAction('Close', self)
        self.cut_action     = QAction('Cut', self)
        self.copy_action    = QAction('Copy', self)
        self.paste_action   = QAction('Paste', self)
        self.font_action    = QAction('Font', self)
        self.color_action   = QAction('Color', self)
        self.about_action   = QAction('Qt', self)

        # Поскольку это Notepad, должен быть текстовый редактор, поэтому, конечно,
        # в функции инициализации класса должен быть создан экземпляр элемента управления QTextEdit:
        self.text_edit = QTextEdit(self)

        # С помощью функции вырезания и вставки мы естественно думаем 
        # о буфере обмена и классе QMimeData:
        self.mime_data = QMimeData()                    # QMimeData
        self.clipboard = QApplication.clipboard()       # буфере обмена

        # Вызвать метод setCentralWidget() класса QMainWindow, чтобы установить
        # центральный элемент управления главного окна, 
        # в котором мы устанавливаем поле редактирования текста text_edit для центрального 
        # элемента управления. 
        self.setCentralWidget(self.text_edit)
        # Вызовите метод resize(), чтобы установить для окна соответствующий размер;
        self.resize(450, 600)

        self.menu_init()
        # После того, как строка меню установлена, мы можем установить панель инструментов:
        self.toolbar_init()
        # Настройка строки состояния очень проста. 
        self.status_bar_init()

        self.action_init()    # установить действия

        self.text_edit_int()  

    def menu_init(self):
        """ добавляем соответствующее действие в строку меню: """

        # Видно, что мы можем добавлять к нему действия, вызывая метод addAction(). 
        # Метод addSeparator(), как следует из названия, добавляет разделитель, что означает,
        # что close_action отделено от четырех вышеуказанных действий, что выглядит более организованным.

        self.file_menu.addAction(self.new_action)
        self.file_menu.addAction(self.open_action)
        self.file_menu.addAction(self.save_action)
        self.file_menu.addAction(self.save_as_action)
        self.file_menu.addSeparator()
        self.file_menu.addAction(self.close_action)

        self.edit_menu.addAction(self.cut_action)
        self.edit_menu.addAction(self.copy_action)
        self.edit_menu.addAction(self.paste_action)
        self.edit_menu.addSeparator()
        self.edit_menu.addAction(self.font_action)
        self.edit_menu.addAction(self.color_action)

        self.help_menu.addAction(self.about_action)

    def toolbar_init(self):
        self.file_toolbar.addAction(self.new_action)
        self.file_toolbar.addAction(self.open_action)
        self.file_toolbar.addAction(self.save_action)
        self.file_toolbar.addAction(self.save_as_action)

        self.edit_toolbar.addAction(self.cut_action)
        self.edit_toolbar.addAction(self.copy_action)
        self.edit_toolbar.addAction(self.paste_action)
        self.edit_toolbar.addAction(self.font_action)
        self.edit_toolbar.addAction(self.color_action)

    def status_bar_init(self):
        # Нам просто нужно вызвать метод showMessage() и передать состояние,
        # которое программа хочет отобразить при открытии программы.
        self.status_bar.showMessage('Ready to compose')

    def action_init(self):
        # Передайте параметр QIcon через метод setIcon(), чтобы установить значок действия.
        #    Метод setShortCut() используется для установки сочетания клавиш. 
        #      Здесь мы устанавливаем сочетание клавиш нового действия на Ctrl + N.
        #      Тогда нажатие Ctrl+N эквивалентно нажатию этого действия (независимо от платформы, 
        #      здесь используется Ctrl равномерно. (Даже на Mac, но после запуска программы пользователи
        #      Mac должны нажать Ctrl + N). 
        #    Метод setToolTip() можно использовать для установки небольшого всплывающего приглашения. 
        #      Когда указатель мыши находится над действием, будет отображаться соответствующее
        #      приглашение (конечно, мы также можем использовать этот метод для других объектов, 
        #      таких как QPushButton). 
        #    Метод setStatusTip() предназначен для установки информации в строке состояния. 
        #      Когда курсор мыши находится над действием, строка состояния отображает 
        #      соответствующую информацию. 
        #  Наконец, мы связываем сработавший сигнал new_action с пользовательской функцией слота:

        self.new_action.setIcon(QIcon('images/new.ico'))
        self.new_action.setShortcut('Ctrl+N')
        self.new_action.setToolTip('Create a new file')
        self.new_action.setStatusTip('Create a new file')
        self.new_action.triggered.connect(self.new_func)

        self.open_action.setIcon(QIcon('images/open.png'))
        self.open_action.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')
        self.open_action.setToolTip('Open an existing file')
        self.open_action.setStatusTip('Open an existing file')
        self.open_action.triggered.connect(self.open_file_func)

        self.save_action.setIcon(QIcon('images/save.png'))
        self.save_action.setShortcut('Ctrl+S')
        self.save_action.setToolTip('Save the file')
        self.save_action.setStatusTip('Save the file')
        self.save_action.triggered.connect(lambda: self.save_func(self.text_edit.toHtml()))

        self.save_as_action.setIcon(QIcon('img/save_as.png'))
        self.save_as_action.setShortcut('Ctrl+A')
        self.save_as_action.setToolTip('Save the file to a specified location')
        self.save_as_action.setStatusTip('Save the file to a specified location')
        self.save_as_action.triggered.connect(lambda: self.save_as_func(self.text_edit.toHtml()))

        self.close_action.setIcon(QIcon('img/exit.png'))    # close.ico
        self.close_action.setShortcut('Ctrl+E')
        self.close_action.setToolTip('Close the window')
        self.close_action.setStatusTip('Close the window')
        self.close_action.triggered.connect(self.close_func)

        self.cut_action.setIcon(QIcon('img/cut.png'))
        self.cut_action.setShortcut('Ctrl+X')
        self.cut_action.setToolTip('Cut the text to clipboard')
        self.cut_action.setStatusTip('Cut the text')
        self.cut_action.triggered.connect(self.cut_func)

        self.copy_action.setIcon(QIcon('img/copy.png'))
        self.copy_action.setShortcut('Ctrl+C')
        self.copy_action.setToolTip('Copy the text')
        self.copy_action.setStatusTip('Copy the text')
        self.copy_action.triggered.connect(self.copy_func)

        self.paste_action.setIcon(QIcon('img/paste.png'))
        self.paste_action.setShortcut('Ctrl+V')
        self.paste_action.setToolTip('Paste the text')
        self.paste_action.setStatusTip('Paste the text')
        self.paste_action.triggered.connect(self.paste_func)

        self.font_action.setIcon(QIcon('img/font.png'))
        self.font_action.setShortcut('Ctrl+T')
        self.font_action.setToolTip('Change the font')
        self.font_action.setStatusTip('Change the font')
        self.font_action.triggered.connect(self.font_func)

        self.color_action.setIcon(QIcon('img/color.png'))
        self.color_action.setShortcut('Ctrl+R')
        self.color_action.setToolTip('Change the color')
        self.color_action.setStatusTip('Change the color')
        self.color_action.triggered.connect(self.color_func)

        self.about_action.setIcon(QIcon('img/about.png'))
        self.about_action.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        self.about_action.setToolTip('What is Qt?')
        self.about_action.setStatusTip('What is Qt?')
        self.about_action.triggered.connect(self.about_func)

    # В конце у нас остается только поле ввода текста QTextEdit, оставленное неустановленным.
    # Подключите сигнал textChanged к функции слота. 
    # В функции slot(text_changed_func) мы можем установить переменную self.is_saved:
    def text_edit_int(self):
        self.text_edit.textChanged.connect(self.text_changed_func)

    def text_changed_func(self):
        if self.text_edit.toPlainText():
            self.is_saved = False
        else:
            self.is_saved = True

    # Перед созданием нового файла нам нужно определить, сохранен ли текущий текст. 
    # Если нет, появится всплывающее окно с вопросом, хотите ли вы сохранить его. 
    # Если вы нажмете Да, вы вызовете функцию save_func() для его сохранения. 
    # Если вы нажмете Нет, чтобы сохранить, он будет очищен. 
    # Если вы нажмете `Отмена` для отмены, никакие действия не будут предприняты, 
    #   если они были сохранены, вы можете просто очистить поле для редактирования текста;

    def new_func(self):
        if not self.is_saved:
            choice = QMessageBox.question(self, '', 'Do you want to save the text?',
                                          QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No | QMessageBox.Cancel)
            if choice == QMessageBox.Yes:
                self.save_func()
                self.text_edit.clear()
            elif choice == QMessageBox.No:
                self.text_edit.clear()
            else:
                pass
        else:
            self.text_edit.clear()

    # Метод установки действия open_action похож, мы в основном рассмотрим функцию подключенного слота:
    # Логика очень похожа на новое действие, за исключением того, что операция очистки поля 
    # редактирования текста заменяется операцией открытия диалогового окна файла;
    def open_file_func(self):
        if not self.is_saved:
            choice = QMessageBox.question(self, '', 'Do you want to save the text?',
                                          QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No | QMessageBox.Cancel)
            if choice == QMessageBox.Yes:
                self.save_func()
                file, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File', './', 'Files (*.html *.txt *.log)')
                if file:
                    with open(file, 'r') as f:
                        self.text_edit.clear()
                        self.text_edit.setText(f.read())
                        self.is_saved = True
            elif choice == QMessageBox.No:
                file, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File', './', 'Files (*.html *.txt *.log)')
                if file:
                    with open(file, 'r') as f:
                        self.text_edit.clear()
                        self.text_edit.setText(f.read())
                        self.is_saved = True
            else:
                pass
        else:
            file, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File', './', 'Files (*.html *.txt *.log)')
            if file:
                with open(file, 'r') as f:
                    self.text_edit.clear()
                    self.text_edit.setText(f.read())
                    self.is_saved = True

    # Функции слотов 
    def save_func(self, text):
        if self.is_saved_first:
            self.save_as_func(text)
        else:
            with open(self.path, 'w') as f:
                f.write(text)
            self.is_saved = True

    def save_as_func(self, text):
        self.path, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Save File', './', 'Files (*.html *.txt *.log)')
        if self.path:
            with open(self.path, 'w') as f:
                f.write(text)
            self.is_saved = True
            self.is_saved_first = False

    # Функция close_func() ниже аналогична методу реализации события закрытия окна. 
    # Обратите внимание, что поскольку в нашем блокноте используется цвет, мы не можем вызвать 
    # метод toPlainText() класса QTextEdit, поскольку этот метод получает чистый текст, 
    # цвет будет потерян. Метод toHtml() должен быть вызван для сохранения цвета;
    def close_func(self):
        if not self.is_saved:
            choice = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Save File', 'Do you want to save the text?',
                                          QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No | QMessageBox.Cancel)
            if choice == QMessageBox.Yes:
                self.save_func(self.text_edit.toHtml())
                self.close()
            elif choice == QMessageBox.No:
                self.close()
            else:
                pass

    def closeEvent(self, QCloseEvent):
        if not self.is_saved:
            choice = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Save File', 'Do you want to save the text?',
                                          QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No | QMessageBox.Cancel)
            if choice == QMessageBox.Yes:
                self.save_func(self.text_edit.toHtml())
                QCloseEvent.accept()
            elif choice == QMessageBox.No:
                QCloseEvent.accept()
            else:
                QCloseEvent.ignore()

    # Функция слота, связанная с помощью cut_action, выглядит следующим образом:
    # Метод self.text_edit.textCursor() может получить текущий указатель 
    #   текстового поля редактирования (тип QTextCursor), а затем вызвать метод selection(), 
    #   чтобы получить содержимое, в настоящий момент выбранное указателем, но типом в данный 
    #   момент является QTextDocumentFragment, мы Вам нужно вызвать метод toHtml(), 
    #   чтобы получить текстовое содержимое. 
    # Когда пользователь режет, обрезанный текст должен исчезнуть, 
    #   поэтому вызовите метод removeSelectedText() QTextCursor.

    def cut_func(self):
        self.mime_data.setHtml(self.text_edit.textCursor().selection().toHtml())
        self.clipboard.setMimeData(self.mime_data)
        self.text_edit.textCursor().removeSelectedText()

    # Функция слота copy_action выглядит следующим образом, метод тот же, за исключением того, 
    # что текст не нужно удалять в это время:
    def copy_func(self):
        self.mime_data.setHtml(self.text_edit.textCursor().selection().toHtml())
        self.clipboard.setMimeData(self.mime_data)

    # В слоте функции paste_action нам просто нужно вызвать метод insetHtml() 
    # для вставки текста в буфер обмена (этот метод вставит текст в позицию указателя):
    def paste_func(self):
        self.text_edit.insertHtml(self.clipboard.mimeData().html())

    def font_func(self):
        font, ok = QFontDialog.getFont()
        if ok:
            self.text_edit.setFont(font)

    def color_func(self):
        color = QColorDialog.getColor()
        if color.isValid():
            self.text_edit.setTextColor(color)

    # Слот-функция, связанная с about_action, является самой простой, 
    # просто откройте окно сообщения о Qt:
    def about_func(self):
        QMessageBox.aboutQt(self, 'About Qt')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    demo = Demo()
    demo.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]